# SwiftMailer with file spool doesn't store emails

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-3.4

I try to set up SwiftMailer to use the spool file system. I'd follow the steps in the Symfony 3.4 documentation and I can't make it work like I want, the emails keep sending and there are not stocked in the folder I want.

There is my configuration :

**config.yml**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool:
        type: file
        path: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/to/folder/Spool'
    disable_delivery: true
```

**PHP**

```
$transport = new \Swift_SmtpTransport();
$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
$message = (new \Swift_Message())
    ->setSubject('Test of spool email')
    ->setFrom(['test@mail.com' => 'Test mailer'])
    ->setTo('fake@mail.com')
    ->setBody("Email de test");
foreach($listeDestinataires as $desitnataire) {
    $mailer->send($message);
}
```

I tried to empty dev and prod cache, but with no effects.
If I do `php bin/console swiftmailer:debug` I have this result :

```
Configured SwiftMailer Mailers
==============================

 -------------------------- ----------- ------- ---------- ----------------
  Name                       Transport   Spool   Delivery   Single Address
 -------------------------- ----------- ------- ---------- ----------------
  default (default mailer)   null        YES     NO
 -------------------------- ----------- ------- ---------- ----------------
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Default behaviour of Symfony mailer is to send the email messages immediately, but as you configured, it will "spool" the emails instead of sending them directly.

Comment: @Zeljka I don't understand what you want me to disabled. If it's the spool that you want me to disable, its the fonctionality that I want to implement so... And it's not only for testing no ?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html read about spool, I edited my first answer

Comment: Now, when your app sends an email, it will not actually be sent but instead added to the spool. Sending the messages from the spool is done separately. There is a console command to send the messages in the spool: APP_ENV=prod php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send

Comment: @Zeljka O.K. so maybe I don't explain my problem too much, but I know that. My problem is that my emails **aren't stocked**, they're **send**.

Comment: sorry I didnt read descrptin well.. did you try to clean cache? if you are working on production

Comment: @Zeljka yes, and as I say in my post it change nothing.

Comment: Do you try `disable_delivery` in false?

Comment: @SilvioQ I just try it and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending in the correct enviroment DEV or PROD?

Also try this: path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/spool'

Does the directory exists?

Ex.: https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html

Comment: I just try with this path and it doesn't work. For the environment how can I know or change that ?